# Is there any way to join the Identity user table with any other table (Product) of our own in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, identity

Is there any way to join the Identity user table with any other table of our own in MVC 5. Because fetching the data is really difficult. If we want to retrieve user product on the bases of some roles and then their products. So its a join of three tables but join of Products table with other two tables i don't know how to use this. Because User and Roles tables are identity table and belongs to IdentityDbContext.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're trying to improve and existing solution, what is it?  Is your identity data stored in the same database as your product data, or are they separate (presumably SQL) databases?

Comment: I haven't tried this. I am about to create project and have some queries in mind. So that i can do the correct thing from start. Yes database will be the same. But as you know there will be two context one will be the IdentityDbContext and other will be our own. So if we will have two context but the same database. So how that will be done? I just want to know is that will be achieve-able or not?